# Stackdriver export to .txt or PDF on drive/mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've set up an script which reads data from a spreadsheet and sends emails according this data.

Now, I've also set it up to do some simple logging via stackdriver.

What I'd like to do is to export these logs (after/at the end of every execution of the mail-script) to a `.txt` or `.pdf` file which then get saved to a specific Google Drive folder or been send by mail.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find out how to do this, or if its even posible?

Comment: And using the native Logger class, which supports `getLogs()`, is not viable?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to edit a Google docs file if this is what you where thinking of doing.  Your going to have to create your .txt or .pdf file locally then upload the file to Google drive or send it as an email.  Technically if you upload the file as a .txt i think that Google drive will allow you to export it as pdf but i haven't tried with the new version of Google drive.

```
var fileId = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/resume.pdf');
drive.files.export({
  fileId: fileId,
  mimeType: 'application/pdf'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
```

[Downloading google Documents](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents)

I also dont think that you will be able to email a file directly from Google Drive you will have to download the file locally then add send your email.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. 
What I've forgot to mention: The script (apps script) sends mails with the GmailApp.sendEmail command. 

I don't know if we're on the same line about the interpretation, but to be sure: What i'd like to do is to grab the log file / log lines, and export these to a file (.txt of .pdf)  This file then should either be saved to Google Drive, or been send by the MailApp to some mailaddress.   
Sending of files isn't the problem, as the current script already takes files from drive and adds them as an attachment. Only thing is how to export the log to a file?

Comment: To my knowlage app script is only going to be able to read the file if you have a url link to it  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

Comment: This answer has bad information in it.  `Drive.Files.export()` will not accept an object as an argument.  `Drive.Files.export(fileId, mimeType)` has two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver has an error reporting API. [Documentation for Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/)  The API has REST capability, which means that you can call it from Apps Script using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` where `url` is the url needed to get error reporting information.  The base url for the Stackdriver API is: `https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com`  The API must be enabled.

There are multiple methods that can be used with the API.

The method that you probably need is the `list` method, which requires the url:

```
https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{projectName=projects/*}/events
```

where the `projectName` parameter must be a Google Cloud Platform project ID.

See documentation on `list` at: [projects.events.list](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/list)

The return value for that HTTPS Request, *if successful*, is a "response body" with the following structure and data:

```
{
  "errorEvents": [
    {
      object (ErrorEvent)
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "timeRangeBegin": string
}
```

The ErrorEvent is a JSON object with the following structure and data:

```
{
  "eventTime": string,
  "serviceContext": {
    object (ServiceContext)
  },
  "message": string,
  "context": {
    object (ErrorContext)
  }
}
```

So, if you want to send an email with error data from Stackdriver, it won't be sent directly from Stackdriver, you need to make a request to Stackdriver from Apps Script, get the error information, and then send an email from Apps Script.

Of course, you could have your own error handling system, that logged error information to some external target, (Eg. your spreadsheet, or a database) using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

To make the request to the Stackdriver API you would need code something like this:

```
var projectID = "Enter project ID";
var url = 'https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/' + projectID 
 + '/events';
var tkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

var options = {};
options.headers = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tkn}
options.muteHttpExceptions = true;

var rtrnObj = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

Logger.log(rtrnObj.getContentText())
```

I haven't use this API and I haven't tested this code.  If anyone uses it, and has information or finds an error, please make a comment.